# Laravel Eloquent : multiple select and where clause query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to get a query that spits out this from my sales table:

```
For each `Brand`    
   `Brand` {
      this month `sum(quantity)`
      this month last year `sum(quantity)`
      this year `sum(quantity)`
      this last year `sum(quantity)`
      `Brand` name
    }
    Next `Brand` {
      this month `sum(quantity)`
      this month last year `sum(quantity)`
      this year `sum(quantity)`
      this last year `sum(quantity)`
      `Brand` name
    }
```

I have this but its not spitting out anything. If I remove the wheres it will get that sums just not in the date range I need so I know its that issue. I am not sure if I can do multiple wheres

```
public function sales()
    {

        return $this->hasMany('App\Sale', 'account_vip_id', 'vip_id')
                                     ->select('brand', DB::raw('sum(quantity) as month'))->whereMonth('date','=',date('m'))
                                     ->addSelect('brand', DB::raw('sum(quantity) as month_last'))->whereDate('date','=',date('m Y',strtotime("-1 year")))
                                     ->addSelect('brand', DB::raw('sum(quantity) as year'))->whereYear('date','=',date('Y'))
                                     ->addSelect('brand', DB::raw('sum(quantity) as year_last'))->whereYear('date','=', date("Y",strtotime("-1 year")))
                                     ->groupBy('brand');

    }
```

Comment: select must be like that  `->select([])`. selected colmns must be in array

Comment: If I remove the `where` the selects and addSelect work fine

Comment: Move all wheres after "selects".

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately SQL doesn't work like this.  You would need to put your `where` clauses inside of the `sum` functions.  I created a quick query to give you a better idea of what I'm talking about...

```
SELECT 
    brands.name,
    SUM( IF( DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(sales.created_at, '%y-%m'), sales.quantity, 0) ) AS `month`,
    SUM( IF( DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(sales.created_at, '%y-%m'), sales.quantity, 0) ) AS `last_month`,
    SUM( IF( YEAR(CURDATE()) = YEAR(sales.created_at), sales.quantity, 0) ) AS `year`,
    SUM( IF( YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1 = YEAR(sales.created_at), sales.quantity, 0) ) AS `last_year`
FROM brands
INNER JOIN sales ON brands.id = sales.brand_id
GROUP BY brands.name;
```